# oracle database, insert data

Tags: database, oracle, user-defined-types

I'm using Oracle 11g table:

```
create or replace type address as object (
    street varchar2(20),
    city varchar2(10),
    p_code varchar2(8)
    ) not final;
/  
create or replace type name as object (
    title varchar2(5),
    firstName varchar2(8),
    surname varchar2(8)
    ) not final;
/      
create or replace type phone as object 
    (
    homePhone int,
    mobile1 int,
    mobile2 int
    ) not final;
/  

create or replace type person as object (
    pname name,
    pAddress address,
    Pphone phone
    )  not final;
/  
create or replace type employee under person (   
    empId varchar2(5),
    position varchar2(16),
    salary int,
    joinDate date,
    supervisor ref employee);
/
create table tb_employee of employee
    (
    primary key(empID)
)
/
```

data I insert

```
insert into tb_employee values
(
person(name('mr','jone','smith'),address('street','city','post 
code'),phone('11111111111','22222222222','33333333333')),
position('head'),
salary(1111),
joinDate(12-Feb-1994),
empID('001')
)


insert into tb_employee values
(
person(name('mr','jane','smith'),address('street','city','post 
code'),phone('11111111111','22222222222','33333333333')),
position('accountant'),
salary(2222,
joinDate(13-Feb-1995),
empID('002')
)

insert into tb_employee values
(
person(name('miss','ross','smith'),address('street','city','post 
code'),phone('11111111111','22222222222','33333333333')),
position(manager),
salary(333),
joinDate(14-Feb-1996),
empID('003')
)
```

I would like to  insert supervisor to data by using reference function,

for example: 
for head (jone smith) is a supervisor or a manager (miss ross smith),

manager(miss ross smith) is a supervisor of account(Mr jane smith),

thanks!

Comment: Huh?  What is reference function?

Comment: em reference is like foreign key in 1-n relationship,  it could replace join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting records of `employee` type: that applies to *the whole record* so you need to write a VALUES clause which matches the projection of that type.

To populate the REF clause you need to select the reference of the pertinent object. Your first record doesn't have a supervisor, so we pass NULL in this case:

```
insert into tb_employee values
    ( employee(
      name('mr','jone','smith')
        , address('street','city','postcode')
        , phone('11111111111','22222222222','33333333333')
        , '001' -- emp id
        , 'head' -- position
        , 11111 -- salary
        , to_date('12-Feb-1994','dd-mon-yyyy') -- joinDate
        , null-- supervisor
    ))
/
```

For the other records we use the INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM syntax:

```
insert into tb_employee 
select
      employee(
        name('mr','jane','smith')
        , address('street','city','postcode')
        , phone('11111111111','22222222222','33333333333')
        , '002' -- emp id
        , 'accountant' -- position
        , 2222 -- salary
        , to_date('13-Feb-1995','dd-mon-yyyy') -- joinDate
        , ref (m) -- supervisor
    )
from tb_employee m
where m.empid = '001'
/    

insert into tb_employee 
select
      employee(
        name('miss','ross','smith')
        , address('street','city','postcode')
        , phone('11111111111','22222222222','33333333333')
        , '003' -- emp id
        , 'manager' -- position
        , 333 -- salary
        , to_date('14-Feb-1996','dd-mon-yyyy') -- joinDate
        , ref (m) -- supervisor
    ) 
from tb_employee m
where m.empid = '002' 
/
```

Here is [a Oracle LiveSQL demo (free OTN account required)](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:41:103029827465054:::41:SHAREKEY:GE4F2USCLC1CMMNLLPJLKECBC). (It's a shame that Oracle's developer Cloud can't handle user-defined types nicely.)